# System settings won't open with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

OK so from the gui, system settings won't open. When opening settings from the command line I get the following:
(gnome-control-center:71314): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 18:12:01.949: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to initialize the Clutter backend: no available drivers found.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried reinstalling gnome-control-center but it made no difference.